# Gate- setting text for annotation

Tags: annotations, gate

I am trying to set content for a particular annotation in Gate. There are methods to extract content/text for the given annotation in the document. I want to change the text shown by the given annotation that means ultimately it should change the actual text of the document. Is it possible in Gate to change the content of annotations?

**gate.Utils.stringFor(document, annotation) or contentFor** methods gives the text highlighted by the given annotation. COuld not find any method which will set content as well.

```
DocumentContent documentContent = new DocumentContentImpl(value);
        Long start = getAnnotation(annotation).getStartNode().getOffset();
        Long end = getAnnotation(annotation).getEndNode().getOffset();
        doc.edit(start, end, documentContent);
```

I want to edit content of the document. I have tried above method I have also added documentListener to the document. Control goes into contentEdited method but the actual content of the document does not get replaced with new content. Rather document does not get affected at all. Can someone suggest me what to do for this or am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The Document interface has a method for this, the mechanics are described in [DocumentImpl](https://gate.ac.uk/releases/latest/doc/javadoc/gate/corpora/DocumentImpl.html).

However, are you sure that you really need to update the document content? That's the point of having annotations - put whatever you need as annotations on top of the text itself. Then just use the annotation features instead of document content. For instance if you get the Token strings you can reconstruct the text, if you use Token stems you get a stemmed version. Just use Token.newstring instead of changing the content.

Also, it is a cumbersome operation because it has to shift all the annotation offsets.

Comment: Thanks @Yasen. I have used DocumentImpl itself. But that edit functionality has done nothing on the actual document. I need to update the document and also I want to add new annotations through code. That is the use case that I have to update the string content for particular annotations and also add some content to the document and then annotate it. Is it really possible ? How can I provide offsets to add particular annotation?

Comment: Edit method does changes in the xml document. I just had to write the content again in xml file. But as @Yasen said. It is a cumbersome operation. It is not properly working. When I change the content from particular start and end offsets, It is deleting all the nodes between those offsets and adds text in between which results in a bad document and not giving expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution for this. I need to use following method for writing xml

```
File f = new File("/path/to/output.xml");
DocumentStaxUtils.writeDocument(doc, f)
```

And this gives a proper xml output after editing the document